# magento order status automatically update trigger or event

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I want to set like these:
1. When order is not paid in 48 hours, it will be automatically updated as [cancelled] state.
2. When our paypal received a chargeback, claim or dispute, it will be automatically updated as [on hold] state.
3. .....any trigger or event like these.
Any idea or tip is okay for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the cron job. Create the controller action which can be check order status , order placed time , based on this change status. Use url to hit that action in cronjob .